# Using iText7.Net, why dimensions returned by iText.Kernel.Geom.Point are 10 times greater that TextRenderInfo.LineSegment.GetStartPoint()?

Tags: vb.net, itext7, text-extraction, information-extraction

I written a `VB.Net` program that intercept `RENDER_PATH` and `RENDER_TEXT` events generated by `iText7` module.

I have written a little code to find location of `TEXT`.

```
    Dim ascent As LineSegment = t.GetAscentLine()
    Dim descent As LineSegment = t.GetDescentLine()

    Dim initX As Single = descent.GetStartPoint().Get(0)
    Dim initY As Single = descent.GetStartPoint().Get(1)
    Dim endX As Single = ascent.GetEndPoint().Get(0)
    Dim endY As Single = ascent.GetEndPoint().Get(1)
```

For specific PDF page, all values returned by `GetStartPoint()` and `GetEndPoint()` are between 20 and 600.

To find `PATH` values, I have writte following code

```
   Private Sub RenderPath(render As PathRenderInfo)
        For Each sp As Subpath In render.GetPath().GetSubpaths()
            Console.WriteLine(render.GetPath().ToString())
            For Each segment In sp.GetSegments()
                Console.WriteLine("  " & segment.ToString())
                Select Case segment.GetType().FullName
                    Case "iText.Kernel.Geom.Line"
                        Dim oLine As iText.Kernel.Geom.Line = segment
                        Dim oList As List(Of Point) = oLine.GetBasePoints()
                        Dim n = 0
                        For Each p In oList
                            Console.WriteLine("    p" & CStr(n) & ".x: " & CStr(oList(n).GetX()))
                            Console.WriteLine("    p" & CStr(n) & ".y: " & CStr(oList(n).GetY()))
                            n += 1
                        Next
                        Console.WriteLine("    width: " & CStr(oList(0).GetX() - oList(1).GetX()))
                        Console.WriteLine("    height: " & CStr(oList(0).GetY() - oList(1).GetY()))
                    Case "iText.Kernel.Geom.BezierCurve"
                    Case Else
                        Dim i0 = 0
                End Select
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

All location's values returned by `GetX()` and `GetY()` functions are now between ... 200 and 6000 !

Why PATH location's values **seems to be** 10 times greater that TEXT location's values ?

Is that **normal** or is that a **BUG** ?

In `iText7`, what are dimensions of TEXT locations and dimensions of PATH segments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In iText7, what are dimensions of TEXT locations and dimensions of PATH segments ?

Indeed, the coordinates returned by `TextRenderInfo` and those returned by `PathRenderInfo` differ:

- Coordinates returned by `TextRenderInfo` are given in the *default* user space coordinates of the given page, i.e. all active transformations are already accounted for.
- Coordinates returned by `PathRenderInfo`, on the other hand, are given in the *current* user space coordinates - current when the path is constructed and drawn. To transform these coordinates into default user space coordinates, you have to apply the CTM (current transformation matrix) to the path. You can retrieve the CTM using the `GetCTM` method of the path render info object.

That different render info classes return coordinates in conceptually different  coordinate system probably isn't intuitive and should be made clearer.

In case of your document page the CTM appears to be a scaling transformation by a factor of `0.1`.

Comment: fyi, PathRenderInfo return "0.1 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 1"; I hope that means that factor between both coordinates is equal to 0.1 in both directions X and Y.

Comment: *"I hope that means that factor between both coordinates is equal to 0.1 in both directions X and Y"* - indeed, it does - the matrix described that way has 0.1, 0.1, 1 on the main diagonal and the rest zeros. Thus, this transformation is purely scaling by 0.1.

Comment: and, I suppose that the last 1 value in matrix is for Z coordinate that is not used for a PDF that has only 2 dimensions ?

Comment: PDF only allows 3x3 matrices with 0, 0, 1 in the third column as transformation matrices. The reason is that the canvas plain is embedded in R³ as the plain with z=1, so all transformations must keep the z coordinate at 1.